# Function from factory not working, but when used in controller it works. Why?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function called updatedUser() that I defined in a factory.  If I inject factory and assign the function to the scope to be used in the view and then invoke it, it doesn't work properly.  I expect it to update the user.  Instead it just creates a new user.

However when I take that same function and define it in the controller and invoke it in the view, it works as expected.  I don't get it!  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

Factory

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('casemanagerApp')
  .factory('$cmUserData', $cmUserData);

  function $cmUserData($log, Restangular) {

    return {
      users: users,
      getUser: getUser,
      updateUser: updateUser
    };

    function users() {
      return Restangular.service('users');
    }

    function getUser() {
      return users().one(1).get().$object;
    }

    function updateUser() {
      Restangular.all('users')
      .post(getUser())
      .then(function(){
        $log.info('User updated');
      });
    }

  }

})();
```

Controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('casemanagerApp')
  .controller('CasePlanGoalsCtrl', CasePlanGoalsCtrl);

  function CasePlanGoalsCtrl($log, $cmUserData) {
    var vm = this;

    // Injections
    vm.user = $cmUserData.getUser();

    // Functions
    // vm.updateUser = $cmUserData.updateUser; <-This doesn't work
    vm.updateUser = updateUser; // This will work

    function updateUser() {
      Restangular.all('users')
      .post(vm.user)
      .then(function() {
        $log.info(vm.user.firstName + ' was updated');
      });
    }

  }

})();
```

View.  See ng-change

```
<md-switch 
    aria-label="Stack Cards" 
    ng-model="vm.user.settings.stackCards" 
    ng-true-value="'isStacked'" 
    ng-false-value="'!isStacked'" 
    ng-change="vm.updateUser()" 
    class="text-uppercase-small pull-right">
    Stack Cards
</md-switch>
```

Comment: What if you alter your controller's updateUser to call through to your service. function updateUser() { $cmUserData.updateUser();}; Does that work as expected?

Comment: @shieldstroy I tried that but that doesn't work either.  The result is the same as calling like I'm doing in the above code.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Does it give you any errors or anything in the console when you try that? Are your other calls using the Restangular service working?

Comment: No errors. Everything else using Restangular service is working as expected.

Comment: So if you log (or put a breakpoint) in your services' updateUser function it doesn't even go in there right? So weird... can you recreate the issue on a plunkr or codepen? If you have your controller set up to call through to the service and put a breakpoint on the line that calls the service ($cmUserData.updateUser()) can you see the function listed as a property on $cmUserData?

Comment: I could try and recreate it in Plunker but I'm using a json server for the data, which plunker doesn't have, so it may be a big task.

What's happening is when I run the function from the factory it adds a new user to the /users instead of updating users/1

Comment: Ohhh of course you said that. Reading is hard. Ok... a plunkr might not be that helpful then. I have an idea but I'm not sure if it's right... I'm not too familiar with Restangular. I'm putting it as an answer because I want to write the code out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is working but it's actually doing something different than your factory. It is using the vm.user object long after Restangular.getUser() has been called to fill that variable. In order to break your controller and make it function the same as your factory, change this:

```
function updateUser() {
  Restangular.all('users')
  .post(vm.user)
  .then(function() {
    $log.info(vm.user.firstName + ' was updated');
  });
}
```

to

```
function updateUser() {
  Restangular.all('users')
  .post($cmUserData.getUser())
  .then(function() {
    $log.info(vm.user.firstName + ' was updated');
  });
}
```

Your controller has given Restangular a chance to resolve the object it is calling, whereas your service is calling the getUser function and immediately trying to use the result of that to do a POST.

If the above code breaks in the same way that your service breaks, then you at least know why the issue is happening. It's because Restangular is giving you an object that it promises to fill, but when your service updateUser function tries to use that object it isn't filled yet.

Restangular returns an object immediately when you call getUser, but at that moment there is *nothing in that object*! It is a shell that Restangular will fill when the call from the server comes back. You need to make sure you are passing an actual user object to your factory.

There isn't an obvious answer to this. Maybe you cache the result of getUser in your factory, or maybe you pass the user into your updateUser() factory function. I suspect Restangular has a way it suggests that you do this, but I'm not that familiar with it so I can't help out much with the specific there.

Comment: The first piece of code is the piece that works.  I want to use the function from the service and not the function in the controller.  But I can only get it to work if use the function in the controller.  So what's not working it just the updateUser() function in the factory.  That's what I'm clueless as the why it doesn't work when it's basically the same function is being used in the ctrl and that one works.

Comment: I know the first piece works, I'm just trying to make it break in the same exact way that your factory is broken. If you change it to the second implementation then it <i>should</i> break. If it does break, then you know what the problem is.

Comment: Oh..duh.  Yeah, that breaks.  Good lookin' out.  So it's the $cmUserData.getUser() that's the problem?

Comment: I editted my answre to make it hopefully more clear.

Comment: I fixed it!  You were a big help.  I'll post my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to pass vm.user to the factory's updateUser() function because of all the awesome stuff @shieldstroy said:

Factory

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('casemanagerApp')
  .factory('$cmUserData', $cmUserData);

  function $cmUserData($log, Restangular) {

    return {
      users: users,
      getUser: getUser,
      updateUser: updateUser
    };

    function users() {
      return Restangular.service('users');
    }

    function getUser() {
      return users().one(1).get().$object;
    }

    function updateUser(model) {
      Restangular.all('users')
      .post(model)
      .then(function(){
        $log.info('User updated');
      });
    }

  }

})();
```

Controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('casemanagerApp')
  .controller('CasePlanGoalsCtrl', CasePlanGoalsCtrl);

  function CasePlanGoalsCtrl($log, $cmUserData) {
    var vm = this;

    // Injections
    vm.user = $cmUserData.getUser();

    // Functions
    vm.updateUser = $cmUserData.updateUser;

  }

})();
```

View. See ng-change

```
<md-switch 
    aria-label="Stack Cards" 
    ng-model="vm.user.settings.stackCards" 
    ng-true-value="'isStacked'" 
    ng-false-value="'!isStacked'" 
    ng-change="vm.updateUser(vm.user)" 
    class="text-uppercase-small pull-right">
    Stack Cards
</md-switch>
```